# jquery template index outside each

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Here is the code I am using

```
<script id="templateGroups" type="text/html">
    <li>
        {{ChildList.Id}}
        <a href="#t${Id}" class="tab-sub-link tab_link ">${Tag}</a>
            <ul>
                {{each ChildList}}
                ${( $data.TagSlug = Tag.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g,'-') ),''}
                <li>
                    <a id="${ParentTag}-${TagSlug}" onclick="_NewsManager.NewsListCall(${Id})"></a>
                    <a href="#${ParentTag}-${TagSlug}" >${Tag}</a>
                </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

So basically I want to put the first child's Id outside and prior to `{{each}}`; where i have used `{{ChildList.Id}}`

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm okay I found the code, as `{{each ChildList}}` will iterate over the list of `ChildList`

`${ChildList[0].Id}` will get the First Object and then its property `Id` and will print it